# Writing code below "ExcelWriter" - Python/Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am working with Openpyxl to automate excel tasks. I have created three pivot tables and used the "ExcelWriter" function to insert those pivot tables back into the excel file. That work very well, I was able to insert the pivot tables into the excel file. the problem is, if I write any code after "writer.save()", the pivot tables wont show up on the sheet. What am I doing wrong and how do i fix this? If i write the code and "save" it (wb.save("Test.xlsx")), i wont see anything on the pivot table sheets

Code:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Test.xlsx")
wb.create_sheet("Results")


Results = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Results')

Results['A3'] = 'Weekly Average Spend'
Results['A4'] = 'Cost Per Trip'
Results['A5'] = 'Average Trips Per Week'
Results['A6'] = 'Total Spend'
wb.save('Test.xlsx') 


wb.create_sheet("sumPiv")
df4 = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx","SQL")
Costpiv = pd.pivot_table(df4,index = ['Ship_Date_Year'],
                           values = ['CustomerFuel'],
                           aggfunc = ('sum'),
                           margins = True)

with pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer: 
    Costpiv.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sumPiv")
writer.save()     
    
wb.create_sheet("TBID")
df1 = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx","mysheet")
MyPiv1 = pd.pivot_table(df1, index = ['weeknum'], 
                           values = ['TB ID'],
                           aggfunc=('count')) 
with pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer: 
    MyPiv1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="TBID") 
    
writer.save()    
wb.create_sheet('SQLPiv')
df3 = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx","SQL")
SqlPiv = pd.pivot_table(df3,index = ['Ship_Date_Year' , 'Ship_Date_Weeknum'],
                           values = ['CustomerFuel'],
                           aggfunc = ('sum'),
                           margins = True)
with pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer: 
    SqlPiv.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="SQLPiv") 
writer.save()
writer.close()
    
  #Everything works as expected till I write code here. 
  #this is what I would like to write here:
  #Results["B3"] = sumPiv["B2"].value
  
print(wb.get_sheet_names())
print("DONE")
```

Comment: There is no need to save or close the file with a `with` statement, the file is automatically closed after the code block.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen. If I dont save or close the file then the pivot table doesnt appear on the sheets. How would I fix that?

Comment: please provide an example of Text.xlsx so we can reproduce the issue.